# Can I screen cast / screen mirror and use the phone at the same time?

Tags: samsung, screencast

I have a Samsung Galaxy 6 and Google Play Movies app running. I can screen mirror to the TV but as soon as I try to use my phone ***for other things*** like check my email the video stops playing.

Is there a way I can start the video (screen cast/screen mirror) and then use my phone ***for other things*** at the same time?

Here is what my screen looks like:

[image]

I select it and then I see this screen:

[image]

FYI I couldn't create the tag "Screen Mirroring". Here is a description if someone wants to create it, http://www.samsung.com/ie/support/skp/faq/1057791.

Comment: Are you using a Chromecast to do the mirroring, or something else like software built in to the TV?

Comment: It's a Samsung Smart TV. When you select inputs it says Screen Mirroring. I added more information.